# Spring inject different bean depending on current scope

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

I have two beans of the same class defined:

```
@Bean
@Scope("singleton")
public MyBean myBeanSingleton(){
    return new MyBean()
}

@Bean
@Scope("request")
public MyBean myBeanRequest(){
    return new MyBean()
}
```

And another prototype scoped bean:

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype") 
public class MyPrototype {
    @Autowired
    private MyBean myBean
}
```

Is it possible for the Spring Application context to inject correct bean automatically when there is no request available?
I would like for the `myBeanRequest` to be injected when getting `MyPrototype` bean in a web context (for example in controller) and i would like the `myBeanSingleton` to be injected when there is no web context (for example when i run some code via the Quartz scheduler).

Currently spring tries to inject the `myBeanRequest` every time, therefore  it fails when there is no request available.

I would very much like to stick with ONE bean definition of `MyPrototype` because there will be many different beans with will require similar behaviour, therefore using qualifier and two different bean definitions (for request and singleton) is not suitable in my case.

Maybe there is some spring component that would allow me to choose programatically which bean to inject?

Comment: have you tried spring profiles?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html

Comment: Hi, spring profiles would not allow me to use both scenarios at the same time. I would have to choose if i want the request bean or singleton bean. I would like for spring to automatically inject correct bean depending on whether there is an web request available or not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring is highly versatile, but currently, you have two beans of same class without any qualifier, so Spring has no way to distinguish them. Even at the lowest level of manually using `ApplicationContext.getBean()`, you can only pass a class and a name.

And I am sorry to say that, but I am afraid that you have a major architectural design problem here. The Spring way would be respect the layered architecture. That means that a bean should lie in only one *layer* either web layer (controller, interceptor, filter) - and it should not make sense to use it without an available request because its use should only be to help in processing a one, or in a non web layer (say service or persistence) and it should work without knowing what http means. And the rule is that web can call non web but the opposite should never occur.

So my advice would be to carefull class your beans in the correct layers, and split the ones that currently belongs to both side in 2 distinct beans. That may be a good deal of work, but if you proceed with a weird design it could become worse when time goes...

I know it is not the expected answer, but it is the best I can give you.

Comment: I was suspecting exactly the same thing, and i am inclined to accept it as answer. I understand that from the service-web perspective this kind of separation is the proper way, but if i am to expand my scenario to other, custom (defined by me) scopes it seems to be a limitation of spring framework. Maybe there is a way to programatically return whichever bean i choose? Some kind of method that is run on every `@Autowire` attempt that i could implement which checks what is the most specific scope available and return correct bean?

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I would do:

Create a RequestMyBean and SessionMyBean that extend a common interface 'MyBean'.

Then

```
     @Component
     @Scope("prototype") 
     public class MyPrototype {
        @Autowired(required=false)
        private RequestMyBean myReqBean

        @Autowired(required=false)
        private SessionMyBean mySessBean

        public MyBean getMyBean(){
             if(myReqBean != null){
                 return myReqBean;
             }
             return mySessBean;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Actually it would not work in my scenario. As i said i would have multiple (over 100 beans) with similar behaviour so i would require for every programmer to rewrite code for each of them. Additionally in production there are actually 4 different beans for MyBean (singleton, singleton from child context, session and request) - therefore the code would be even more complex than that. And i do not exclude the possibility of adding other custom scoped "MyBeans"

Comment: I see. Maybe you could look at the Spring class that throws an exception when it's not able to autowired the request bean when not present. Then try to overload it so that it will try to look in the session scope. This is a solution that will be hard to maintain when you migrate to new spring versions though...